# variable getting lost sent in querystring from previous page on refreshing in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code in which I'm going from one page to other and passing a variable in querystring.
I'm getting that variable in next page and showing the results related to that. But when I refresh the second page, it says the variable which I got from `first page is undefined.

following is link

```
<a href="next.php?name=men-shoes">shoes</a>
```

next.php is as follows

```
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="one">one<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="two">two<br>

<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
    var data = $('input[type="checkbox"]').serialize(),
        loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0];
    $.post('/ajax-post-url/', data);
    if(history.pushState){
        history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname+'?'+data);
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm getting lcSearchVal on second page firstly but when I refresh the page then I'm getting the error in browser that name is undefined index.

How to correct this so that when I refresh the page it should be in the same state? i.e. the checkboxes which I have checked should remain checked and lcSearchVal should be read in same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `$lcSearchVal` in the URL that you push:

```
history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname+'?name=<?php echo urlencode($lcSearchVal) ?>&'+data);
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution would be to make use of sessions. So your code would become:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && ! isset($_GET['name']))
{
   $lcSearchVal = $_SESSION['name'];
}
else
{
    $lcSearchVal = $_GET['name']; // do not forget to sanitize this data
    $_SESSION['name'] = $lcSearchVal;
}
```

Comment: This looks fyn.but i m getting this issue at the tym when i have checked checkbox given in html.like when i m on second page without any checkbox selected then it works fine.but when i select the checkbox and then refresh than i m getting undefined index name error.

Comment: Either I didn't understand your point or you have some extra code which you didn't post. Using the above method will remove the notice about undefined index `name`